How i will install wifi usb driver 2310:1a2b SciIncX 802.11n NIC in ubuntu 24.04 for desktop
I am new user in Ubuntu 24.04. But my desktop wifi is not found. So i used usb wifi driver 2310:1a2b SciIncX 802.11n NIC. But i cant find any solution for install the driver, so that i can use wifi internet.
Please help me.

Any results from terminal for usb_modeswitch -KW -v 2310 -p 1a2b

you should return it. It is a fake  and therefor will not work  2310 is a fake vendor ID  https://usb-ids.gowdy.us/read/UD?restrict=2

What i need to do.? please anyone give me the step by step solution, so that i can install wifi driver.
